# php regex - Scraping images from javascript object

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to scrape images from the mark-up of certain webpages. These webpages all have a slideshow. Their sources are contained in javascript objects on the page. I'm thinking i need to get_file_contents("http://www.example.com/page/1"); and then have a preg_match_all() function that i can input a phrase(ie. "\"LargeUrl\":\"", or "\"Description\":\"") and get the string of characters until it hits the next quotation mark it finds.

```
var photos = {}; 
photos['photo-391094'] = {"LargeUrl": "http://www.example.org/images/1.png","Description":"blah blah balh"};
photos['photo-391095'] = {"LargeUrl": "http://www.example.org/images/2.png","Description":"blah blah balh"};
photos['photo-391096'] = {"LargeUrl": "http://www.example.org/images/3.png","Description":"blah blah balh"};
```

I have this function, but it returns the entire line after the input phrase. How can i modify it to look for whatever's after the input phrase up until it hits the next quotation mark it finds? Or am i doing this all wrong and there's a better way?

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.example.org/page/1");
$word = "\"LargeUrl\":\"";

if(preg_match_all("/(?<=$word)\S+/i", $page, $matches))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Ideally the function would return a an array like the following if i inputed "\"LargeUrl\":\""

```
$matches[0] = "http://www.example.org/images/1.png";
$matches[1] = "http://www.example.org/images/2.png";
$matches[2] = "http://www.example.org/images/3.png";
```

Comment: Do you realize that most likely it is illegal?

Comment: they're user uploaded images. I will be getting permission from each user.

Comment: You also checked that this website doesn't already have an API for this purpose, right? What website is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parenthesis to capture the parts you're interested in. A simple regex to do it is

```
$word = '"LargeUrl":';
$pattern = "$word" . '\s+"([^"]+)"';

preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $page, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a regex that will match each image URL, but you could also, if its easier for you, match the whole object and then json_decode() the matched string

Comment: Ack. Sorry, didn't look at your example where they have it broken up line by line. Matching chunks of the line with parens, as suggested above, is the way to go. I just wanted to throw out an alternate, but it was a tad misguided.

Answer (score 0):

I have perfect solution for you....use the following code and you will get your needed result.

```
preg_match_all('/{"LargeUrl":(.*?)"(.*?)"/', $page, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $result[2][$i];
        echo "</pre>";

}
```

**Thanks......p2c**